# slider thumb does not drag on its own iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I am implementing the UISlider and it is working fine.

```
CGFloat y = self.view.frame.size.width - (self.view.frame.size.height-20) + 350;
self.currentTimeSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-285,y,self.view.frame.size.width-120,self.view.frame.size.height-20)];
self.currentTimeSlider.minimumValue=0;
self.currentTimeSlider.maximumValue = self.audioPlayer.getAudioDuration;
[self.currentTimeSlider addTarget:self
                               action:@selector(sliderChanged:)
                     forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside)];

self.currentTimeSlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
self.currentTimeSlider.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {

    NSLog(@"slider = %f",self.currentTimeSlider.value);
    textView.hidden=NO;
    NSString *bgFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"inside"
                                                           ofType:@"png"];
    bgimg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bgFilePath];
    [bgImageView setImage:bgimg];
    if([self.audioPlayer  getCurrentAudioTime]==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"song finished.");
        NSString *bgFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"screen5"
                                                               ofType:@"jpg"];
        bgimg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bgFilePath];
        [bgImageView setImage:bgimg];
        textView.hidden=YES;
    }

        long currentPlaybackTime = [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime];
        if ((currentPlaybackTime / [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration]) > self.currentTimeSlider.value )
   {
        self.currentTimeSlider.value = currentPlaybackTime / [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration];

    self.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                             [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

    self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration] - [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];
    }
    else
    {

        self.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                 [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

        NSLog(@"time elapsed = %d",self.timeElapsed.text);



        self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                              [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration] - [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];
    }

}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)currentTimeSlider
{
    NSLog(@"sliderValue = %f",self.currentTimeSlider.value);
    NSLog(@"sliderValuesss = %f",self.currentTimeSlider.value);

    [self.audioPlayer setCurrentAudioTime:self.currentTimeSlider.value];


    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];


}
```

My problem is that the slider thumb does not drag on its own. But on manual slider drag the timer updates as well as the song. But if I comment the minimum and maximum value then the slider drags on its own but manual slide starts the song from the start.

```
self.currentTimeSlider.minimumValue=0;
self.currentTimeSlider.maximumValue = self.audioPlayer.getAudioDuration;
```

Any idea please how can I achieve both manual and automatic slider drag.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "does not drag on its own"? Do you mean you are changing the value and you want the slider to update? I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: Also, the words "mouse down" have no place in an iOS app. Where is the mouse? :)

Comment: I didn't use the word mouse down. I mean when I hit the play button the song plays but the slider thumb does not move. It stays constant at one place.

Comment: just a note about your comment... "When scrubber is mouseDown"

Answer (score 1):

You are using *`NSTimer`* which runs over a separate thread, not on main thread and UI is handled by main thread.

So, to resolve your problem, you need to fire an event on main thread to update your UI using this method: 
[performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:NO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF)

In that selector method write your code to update your custom slider value.

Also one more suggestion, do not create a custom slider each time, you can create it at the time of viewDidLoad, right now its in `updateTime`, it will cause memory concerns. Rather than in this method only change slider value to updated one.

Comment: Also you set `self.currentTimeSlider.maximumValue = self.audioPlayer.getAudioDuration;` but when you set a value you use `currentPlaybackTime / [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration]`. I think you just want to use `currentPlaybackTime`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still the slider does not move on its own.